# New leads bypass assignment rules because of SOAP API

Tags: leads

I get my leads in through a PHP form using the SOAP API. It looks like it automatically assigns each lead to the account owner used to authenticate the connection, rather than using the lead assignment rules that I have in place.

How can I remedy this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the SOAP Partner API you will need to set the [AssignmentRuleHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_assignmentruleheader.htm).

With this you can control if the default assignment rule should be applied, or if an alternative rule, identified by the Id, should be used instead.